# Use ESC/POS Printing Command to print image in thermal printer

Tags: c++, qt, thermal-printer

Hi i am using QT C++ to print image by thermal printer (Xprinter XP-D300H) . I using [POS command](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/CSN-A2%20User%20Manual.pdf) to send byte data to printer by UART. I can print the text and its formats are completely normal. Buy i have a problem when printing image.
This is my printing function:

```
QByteArray printData = "\x12\x2A";
printData.append(image.width() );
printData.append(image.height() );
char bitIndex = 0;
char recordByte = 0x00;
// Convert the image to 32-bit format to handle transparency
QImage tempImage = image.convertToFormat(QImage::Format_ARGB32);
// Create a new image with 1-bit per pixel (monochrome)
QImage bitonalImage(tempImage.size(), QImage::Format_Mono);
bitonalImage.fill(Qt::white); // Set the background to white
// Iterate through each pixel in the image
for (int y = 0; y < tempImage.height(); ++y) {
    for (int x = 0; x < tempImage.width(); ++x) {
    // Get the color of the current pixel
    QRgb color = tempImage.pixel(x, y);
    // Calculate the intensity (brightness) of the pixel
    int intensity = qGray(color);
    if(intensity > 128){
        recordByte = recordByte | ( 0x01 << bitIndex);
        //Log to describe what I want to print
        printf("*");
    }else{
        printf(" ");
    }
bitIndex ++;
if(bitIndex > 7){
    printData.append(recordByte);
    bitIndex = 0 ;
    recordByte = 0x00;
    }
}
printf("\n");
}
//send all byte to printer
mRs232_printer->sendData(printData.data(),printData.size());
```

This is terminal 's result

On Terminal
[image]

This is what the printer printed

[image: Printer printed]

I am trying to making printer print image look like i log in terminal. My port and my baudrate is correct because i can print text normaly.

Comment: Are you expecting pixel resolution in the output or ASCII art? Your recordByte is some mash of the pixel data and the printer is expecting character data in whatever mode you have it in.  If you want the * and (space) you need to printData.append('*'), etc.

Comment: First byte you send is incorrect. You have `\x12` should be `\x1b`. Also before sending width and height you also need to send the mode. See the table on page 30 of the manual you linked.

Comment: @Syntactics ASCII art just for  describe the image I intend to print. The data that I printed was saved in QbyteArray printData and sent to the printer via Rs232 port
​